# Where has "window-based" project gone?

Tags: ios, xcode4, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I've recently bought two books about MonoTouch so that I can start learning to build iPhone applications.  Both books in their tutorials refer to creating a "Window-based" project to start learning with, however that just doesn't seem to be there in the new project options.  Instead MonoDevelop shows the following as the available project types:

- Empty Project
- Utility Application
- Master-Detail Application
- Single View Application
- Tabbed Application
- OpenGL Application

I'm using the MonoDevelop 2.8 and MonoTouch 4.2.2.  Can anyone tell me where this project type has gone, if I can get it back, and if not which one I should be using instead?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The closest equivalent is Single View application.