# what are the steps needed to modify an empty application to a window-based application in MonoTouch using Xcode 4.2?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xcode4.2, monodevelop

In followup to [Where has "window-based" project gone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688981/where-has-window-based-project-gone), what are the steps needed to modify an empty application to a window-based application in MonoTouch using Xcode 4.2?

I am learning iOS development and have read about 1 1/2 books (most recently, ["iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide (2nd Edition)"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321773772) -- nice book). I found instructions [here](http://plusangel.wordpress.com/2011/12/06/window-based-application-template-in-xcode-4-2/) on converting an empty application to a window-based application for Objective-C.

I tried applying these steps to a sample MonoTouch application and I get run-time errors related to needing a root view controller.

Is there a site that lists the steps in small words for simple minds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps I discovered by downloading a window-based application sample from the source code of one of my Monotouch books (http://www.apress.com/9781430231745) and then creating an empty solution. I compared the files and added the things needed to the empty one to make it look (and act) like the window-based one.

- Change the line `UIApplication.Main (args, null, "AppDelegate");` in Main to `UIApplication.Main (args);`.
- Add an AppDelegate-derived class to the file `Main.cs` (inside the namespace):

```
    // The name AppDelegate is referenced in the MainWindow.xib file.
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded its UI and its ready to run
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            // If you have defined a view, add it here:
            // window.AddSubview (navigationController.View);

            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

            return true;
        }
    }
```

- Remove the file `AppDelegate.cs` (delete it from the project).
- Add a new `Empty iPhone Interface Definition` file and name it `MainWindow.xib`.
- Add a new empty C# file and name it `MainWindow.xib.designer.cs`. Insert the following code:

```
    using MonoTouch.Foundation;

    namespace MY_NAMESPACE
    {
        [Register ("AppDelegate")]
        partial class AppDelegate
        {
            [Outlet]
            MonoTouch.UIKit.UIWindow window { get; set; }

            void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
            {
                if (window != null) {
                    window.Dispose ();
                    window = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

- Change `MY_NAMESPACE` to your namespace.
- Open `MainWindow.xib` in the Interface Builder (Xcode 4.2).
- Change the class for the File's Owner to `UIApplication` (third tab - Identity Inspector).
- Add a new `Object` object (search for `object` in the widgets list) and change the class to `AppDelegate`.
- Add a new `Window` object.
- Select the File's Owner, click the last tab in the inspectors (Connections Inspector) and connect the delegate link to the `App Delegate`.
- Select the App Delegate and connect the window link to your new window.
- Save the MainWindow.xib file changes in Interface Builder.
- Return to MonoDevelop.
- Open the file `Info.plist` and change the Main Interface to `MainWindow`.

I'm getting a warning about `Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch`, but the application seems to run. I suspect that the warning is coming from some difference in the `.xib` file. Perhaps the Xcode 3.2 version includes some indication that this is the root view controller. How do I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 0):

> have read about 1 1/2 books

Most MonoTouch books were written before XCode 4 and things changed a bit afterward. Note: AFAIK only [iOS Development using MonoTouch Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849691460) (from [Dimitris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577486/dimitris-tavlikos)) is more recent (but I have not *yet* read this one ;-).

> Is there a site that lists the steps in small words for simple minds?

There are a lot of [tutorials and samples](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios) on Xamarin's web site to help you cover those new (and changed) things. Source code for the [samples](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/samples) are also available on [github](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/) for testing or simply browsing them.

Lots of other web sites and great blogs are also talking about MonoTouch, new and uncommon API... Googling around always lead to more surprises :)

> I get run-time errors related to needing a root view controller.

Error? or siply a warning ? iOS5 warns about missing root view controllers. Here's the code being used in [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog)'s [Sample](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/Sample/Main.cs) application.

```
// On iOS5 we use the new window.RootViewController, on older versions, we add the subview
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (5, 0))
    window.RootViewController = navigation; 
else
    window.AddSubview (navigation.View);
```